# Convert SVG to PNG with Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, svg, cairo

**Question: Which reproducible process can enable Windows Python users to render a SVG image into PNG?**

---

Many questions/answers (such as [Convert SVG to PNG in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589358/convert-svg-to-png-in-python) and [Server-side SVG to PNG (or some other image format) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932408/server-side-svg-to-png-or-some-other-image-format-in-python), which are not duplicates for the reasons explained below) explain how to convert a SVG to PNG with Python.

Unfortunately, **none of them are ready-to-use for Python + Windows**. After more than 20 minutes, and many different attempts, I'm still unable to do it.
More details about failing attempts:

- Installing `cairo` on Windows is not straightforward, we have to use Gohlke's binaries [Intalling pycairo with Python 3.7 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178579/intalling-pycairo-with-python-3-7-on-windows) :

  ```
  pip install pycairo-1.20.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
  ```
- Even once `cairo` is installed, `rsvg` (from main answers of [Server-side SVG to PNG (or some other image format) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932408/server-side-svg-to-png-or-some-other-image-format-in-python), [Convert SVG to PNG in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589358/convert-svg-to-png-in-python)) is not available for Windows:

  ```
  pip install rsvg   # or pyrsvg
  > ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyrsvg
  ```
- Solutions with `svglib` or `reportlab` don't work out-of-the-box on Python3 + Windows:

  ```
  from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
  from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF, renderPM
  drawing = svg2rlg("a.svg")
  renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, "file.png", fmt="PNG")
  ```

  Indeed:

  ```
  AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'fromstring'
  ```

So a solution - specific for Windows - would be helpful.

Comment: You cannot encode vector graphics data in a format that is raster based without loss of information. You're going to have to answer this question first: How much information are you willing to sacrifice?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm looking for a PNG export, for a given image size, e.g. `width=1000px` (Of course a SVG can be infinitely zoomed without loss of quality, which will not be the case for a PNG, but I'm ok with this).

Comment: That `svglib` example worked for me on Windows, I couldn't reproduce your error.  Is the problem specific to certain SVG files you have?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Which versions of Python, svglib, reportlab do you have? I'll try to pip install the same versions.

Comment: I have Python 3.7.3 installed, and the latest svglib and reportlab (1.0.1 and 3.5.59), which I recently installed from `pip` without specifying a version number for either. Also, could you please edit your question to include the full traceback of that `AttributeError` you were receiving?

Comment: I reinstalled with the same versions than you, and it works indeed. I think you can post this as an answer!

Comment: Did you reinstall Python as well, or just svglib and reportlab?

Comment: Just the two last ones @LukeWoodward.

Comment: You should include updated answers to either or both of the questions you linked, now that you have a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the comments, the solution was to install `svglib` version 1.0.1 and `reportlab` 3.5.59.

Comment: This answer is life saver. I had `reportlab` 3.5.49 and still i was getting Attributerror. But with the required update its working fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really saved my life. Great job!

Comment: I tried using `reportlab 4.0.8` + `svglib 1.5.1` on python `3.11.4` on windows, and I get the following :  

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rlPyCairo'`

Comment: @DanteMarshal: at the time I wrote this answer, `reportlab` 4 hadn't been released. However, having just tried, I can reproduce your error with the same versions of `reportlab` and `svglib` you are using. The fix is merely to install `rlPyCairo`.

Comment: If you have issues with transparency/opacity with this solution either look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68022625/opacity-issue-when-saving-a-svg-in-a-pdf-with-reportlab or at the alternative solution with `CairoSVG`

Answer (score 0):

After comparing several solutions and finding out how to get libcairo working on a Windows computer (which can be a bit tricky) I recommend the following rather simple solution:

1. Install [CairoSVG](https://cairosvg.org), i.e. `pip install CairoSVG`
2. If libcairo-2.dll is not on the Windows path of your computer (i.e. `where libcairo-2.dll` fails) and you do not know where to find it, install the [GTK+ Runtime](https://gtk-win.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Main/Downloads) (<8 MB download, 14 MB when installed) with checkbox **Set up PATH environment variable to include GTK+** checked (or provide the DLL folder path below yourself)

Now it can still happen that `import cairosvg` fails because there might be incompatible dependencies like `zlib1.dll` on your Windows path.
To avoid such complications use the following Python script for conversion, which makes sure that `libcairo-2.dll` and its dependencies are loaded from the same folder. Provide the path to the SVG file as command line argument or in the global variable `PATH_TO_SVG`:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

# locate cairo dll
def _findLibCairoInstallFolder():
    CAIRO_DLL = 'libcairo-2.dll'
    consoleOutput = subprocess.check_output('where ' + CAIRO_DLL)
    assert CAIRO_DLL.encode() in consoleOutput,\
        f"{CAIRO_DLL} not on Windows path. Do you know its install folder? Have you the GTK+ Runtime for Windows installed?"
    cairoDllFirstLocation = consoleOutput.split(b'\r\n')[0].decode()
    cairoDllInstallPath = cairoDllFirstLocation.split(CAIRO_DLL)[0]
    return cairoDllInstallPath

# find or provide path to installation folder of cairo dll
g_cairoDllInstallPath = _findLibCairoInstallFolder()
#g_cairoDllInstallPath = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\GTK2-Runtime\bin"

# locally fix windows environment variable PATH so that libcairo-2.dll can be loaded
def _fixWindowsPathForLib(dllInstallPath):
    # make sure dependencies are loaded from the same folder
    os.environ['PATH'] = os.pathsep.join((dllInstallPath, os.environ['PATH']))

_fixWindowsPathForLib(g_cairoDllInstallPath)
import cairosvg

PATH_TO_SVG = 'example.svg'

def svg2png(inputPath, outputPath):
    with open(inputPath) as fileIn:
        svgCode = fileIn.read()
        cairosvg.svg2png(bytestring=svgCode, write_to=outputPath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        g_inputPath = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        g_inputPath = PATH_TO_SVG
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        g_outputPath = sys.argv[2]
    else:
        g_outputPath = g_inputPath + '.png'

    svg2png(g_inputPath, g_outputPath)
```